# How to run the same test with different fixtures in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to run the exact same Cypress test for a component displayed on two separate pages. To achieve this I thought I'd use a `forEach` statement
so that that same code runs for each "state" (see code below).

The problem is that the code block in the `before` statement starts running for state #2, **before** the tests for state #1 have finished. This results in the tests for state #1 failing (because it has state #2 fixtures).

How can I make the `before` part for state #2 wait for all tests in state #1 to be finished?

```js
const states = [
  { 
    "startPath": "/path1", 
    "fixture": "fixture1"
  },
  { 
    "startPath": "/path2", 
    "fixture": "fixture2"
  }
]

describe('Start test', function() {

  // Loop through both test
  states.forEach((state) => {

    // In this before statement the fixtures are setup
    before(function () {
      cy.flushDB()
      cy.fixture(state.fixture)
        .then(fixtureData => {
          new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            cy.createCollections(fixtureData, resolve, reject)
          )
        })
        .then(() => cy.visit(state.startPath)) 
    })
    
    context('Within this context', function() {
      it(`Can run some test for fixture ${state.fixture}`, function() {
        
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution: I had to wrap it into another `describe` code block and then it worked:

```js
const states = [
  { 
    "startPath": "/path1", 
    "fixture": "fixture1",
    "context": "1"
  },
  { 
    "startPath": "/path2", 
    "fixture": "fixture2",
    "context": "2"
  }
]

describe('Start test', function() {

  // Loop through both test
  states.forEach((state) => {

    // SOLUTION HERE
    describe(state.context, () => {
  
      // In this before statement the fixtures are setup
      before(function () {
        cy.flushDB()
        cy.fixture(state.fixture)
          .then(fixtureData => {
            new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => 
              cy.createCollections(fixtureData, resolve, reject)
            )
          })
          .then(() => cy.visit(state.startPath)) 
      })
      
      context('Within this context', function() {
        it(`Can run some test for fixture ${state.fixture}`, function() {
          
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A third approach can loop a given fixture's data set against one test. Each data set within the fixture will register as its own test.

**integration/example_spec.js**

```
const examples = require('../../fixtures/examples');
// `examples` contains the full contents of the fixture

describe('Using `require`', function () {
    examples.forEach((example) => {
        it('gets its data from a fixture', function () {
            // Do something with each example
        });
    });
});
```

**fixtures/examples.json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Iteration 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Iteration 2"
    }
]
```

See: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3963#issuecomment-483581934

Answer (score 0):

Works for me perfectly in single fixture JSON with multiple data and not stub API

before `describe('Test Single Input Field Form', function()` declare :

```js
const testData = require("../../fixtures/multipleInputFields.json")
```

and then

```js
testData.forEach((data) => {
  const message = data.message
  it("Test Case", function () {
    cy.log("data is:" + data)
    cy.get("#user-message").type(message).should("have.value", message)
    cy.get("#get-input > button").click()
    cy.wait(200)
    cy.get("span#display").should("have.text", message)
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest a slightly different approach? You can put the test in a custom command and reuse it in the test. What you'll end up with is this:

```js
const states = [
  { 
    "startPath": "/path1", 
    "fixture": "fixture1"
  },
  { 
    "startPath": "/path2", 
    "fixture": "fixture2"
  }
]

Cypress.Commands.add('testcase', function() {
  // steps which you want to perform in both scenarios
})

describe('Start test', function() {
  states.forEach((state) => {
    it('first scenario', function() {
      cy.flushDB()
      cy.fixture(state.fixture)
        .then(fixtureData => {
          new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => 
          cy.createCollections(fixtureData, resolve, reject)
          )
        })
        .then(() => cy.visit(state.startPath))
        cy.testcase()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This did solve the issue, but using a nested test (it statement within an it statement) this leads to other unwanted complexities. I came up with a solution.

Comment: What was your solution? You can post it and except your own answer. That's very useful for the community